# Javascript - how to bind 'this' inside an ajax call to the object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this, object-literal

I have an object literal `router`, containing an ajax call. I want to call other functions `this.printMovies()` inside the ajax call but `this` refer to the ajax object.

**How do I escape it and make `this` refer to the `router` object itself?**

```
var router = {  

    //...
    init : function() {
        this.getData("api/movies", "movies", callback);
    },
    getData : function (url, htmlType, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response && response.length > 0) {
                    this.printMovies(response, callback); //'this' refers to ajax
                    this.printMovies(response, callback).bind(this) //still doesn't work
                }
            },
            error: function (response) { console.log("Error:" + response); }
        });
    },
    printMovies : function(){

    },  
}
```

Comment: Try initializing a variable with `$this = this` before `$.ajax` ajax call defn. And refer the router obj in success as `$this`

Comment: That works! This is the answer!

Comment: @ViolaT It works BUT ajax method as an option for that...  Use `context`

Comment: Right. `context` is always a better option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass `context` option to ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  context: this,
  /* other options */
}
```

Now inside ajax callbacks, `this` will refer to `router` object.

Answer (score 1):

Here in this case, the function `getData` holds the context of it's parent object in `this` keyword. So what you can do is, store the reference of `this` in some variable and use it later. like:

```
var router = {  

    //...
    init : function() {
        this.getData("api/movies", "movies", callback);
    },
    getData : function (url, htmlType, callback) {
        var mainObj = this; // line to be noticed

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response && response.length > 0) {
                    // parent object to be used
                    mainObj.printMovies(response, callback); //'this' refers to ajax
                }
            },
            error: function (response) { console.log("Error:" + response); }
        });
    },
    printMovies : function(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the entire success call back with bind it will work:

```
(function (response) {
            if (response && response.length > 0) {
                this.printMovies(response, callback);                                     }
        }).bind(this)
```

Comment: is there a syntax mistake in your example?

Comment: But `this` even in outer scope is referring to ajax options, not `router` object

Comment: I have modified my answer bind the entire success callback with bind(this);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

You might have to do this on your success or getData function

```
getData : function (url, htmlType, callback) {
  ...
}.bind(this),
```

Comment: You can see in my example it tried `this.printMovies(response, callback).bind(this)` and it doesn't work.

Comment: It should be `this.printMovies.bind(this, response, callback)`
But you might have to do it on your success function

Comment: No, `this` isn't `router` object but ajax options object

Comment: Updated with a different suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A very common approach is to assign `this` to a local variable at the beginning of your function.

```
var self = this;
```

Then inside your callback use `self` instead of `this`:

```
self.printMovies(response, callback);
```